# Chat claims my reputation is much lower than it really is

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat

I have >15000 rep on [TeX.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2707/bruno-le-floch), but when logging to `http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends` the area where messages are normally typed is replaced by a notification that I "need 20 rep to chat".   I am correctly logged in (I even appear in the list of people present in the room).

[image: Screenshot of my view in chat]

Comment: I'm a mod over on SF&F, and I can't get into Teacher's Lounge.  It's like the chat isn't recognizing me as a mod.

Comment: @Keen - check that the parent site in chat is the site where you mod

Comment: @ChrisF Already done.

Comment: My problem got fixed when I was busy doing something else :).

Comment: @Keen I've fixed you up

Answer (score 6):

Something went wrong with the API on one of the chat web servers. I can't say precisely what (I wanted to fix it, but once fixed, you can't really look at "what's going on?" anymore). So users hitting that one webserver may intermittendly have had incorrect data (i.e. not all of their accounts) in chat; you were one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Reset your parent site in your chat profile. The account associations were mixed up, nothing to worry.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem got fixed for me at least, so I didn't get time to apply your suggestion.